# Twilio PHP SDK Call Logs

Tags: php, twilio

I am not able to return any of the fields when the key has an underscore.

This returns the value as expected:

```
$calls = $twilio->calls->read([], 20);
        
foreach ($calls as $record) {
  print($record->from);
}
```

This does not return the value:

```
$calls = $twilio->calls->read([], 20);
        
foreach ($calls as $record) {
  print($record->from_formatted);
}
```

Comment: @0stone0, no.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-properties

Comment: Ah, thanks! That is exactly what I was missing. So, instead of `from_formatted`, the correct property that is PHP formatted is `fromFormatted`.